# convert Word and Excel formula to display on html page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-5, ms-word, rich-text-editor

I am developing **online examination system.**

> Question are in ***Word and Excel format*** with **different formula**.

like Following

[image]

**Currently I made it image and store in database.
but it takes to much time to that process and any change or formating also very hard.**

Is there any such editor there I can just paste formula and it convert for to use on html page.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all formula images to svg files and can easily use them in your html pages. I have attached the SVG file for the above formula you have asked.

[Formula SVG file link](https://s4.aconvert.com/convert/p3r68-cdx67/5ipim-iyaev.svg)

Comment: Is there any offline code which i can implement in my project (using mvc5)

Comment: You can use Latex javascript library also to convert all your math formulas. It also works offline.  http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/htmlequations.php

Comment: I tried copy word formula and paste to   Latex  editor but not work .

Comment: see image in my question its in word file I try to copy and paste to editor but not pasted it.  please any implementation example

Comment: the formula given in your word file is a image file then it is hard to convert it to text so either use html to svg converter or just optimize your image with image processing tools to load fastly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153602/discussion-between-nextin-and-pravin).